# Krusader quick view like Midnight commander

Tags: filemanager, krusader

The good old Midnight Commander which came of the original Norton Commander had a quick view, which was menu , right, quick view, so any files selected in the file panel were shown in the other panel, very handy for text files.
It seems Krusader does not have this. nothing in the manual
https://docs.kde.org/stable5/en/krusader/krusader/krusader.pdf
and one can install midnight commander as easy as

```
sudo apt install mc
```

and run as

`mc`

from the command line
but are there any plugins/addons for Krusader to do this?

Comment: and downvoted for what exactly?